# Binding to JobService not possible - alternatives?

Tags: android, service

While migrating from Android's `Service` to `JobService` to meet [changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) for [Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) I noticed that `onBind` is now `final` (see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/job/JobService.java#66).

What's the migration path if I have a bound service in my app, that is a service which my app is starting and needs to communicate with while it is running?

Comment: Any references or  examples? @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Bound Services`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) are not affected by this change! [[source]](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services)

And this actually makes sense, like when you *bind* to a service from, say, an `Activity` then your application is actually *running in foreground* and is exempted from this optimization. Then when the user navigates away from the `Activity`, you would un-bind from the `Service`.

So there is no point in running a *bound service* in background and hence no optimization for it.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!